# Is it possible to configure webpack to not add extra code?

Tags: webpack

If I compile

```
console.log('testing 1 2 3');
```

I get

```
!function(e){var t={};function n(r){if(t[r])return t[r].exports;var o=t[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,n),o.l=!0,o.exports}n.m=e,n.c=t,n.d=function(e,t,r){n.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:r})},n.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},n.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=n(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var r=Object.create(null);if(n.r(r),Object.defineProperty(r,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&t&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var o in e)n.d(r,o,function(t){return e[t]}.bind(null,o));return r},n.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return n.d(t,"a",t),t},n.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},n.p="",n(n.s=0)}([function(e,t){console.log(slug("testing 1 2 3"))}]);
```

What is all this extra code, and is there a way to disable it?

I do want to use require(), but only for modules I make that definitely work in browser already.

Comment: It's code native to webpack, needed for finding your imports and require statements. What is your expectation on what the output *should* look like?

Comment: I just want to pack multiple browser js files into one for organization, but not if it will add extra code

Comment: 21 bytes prepended to your output file seems to be an extremely small price to pay for the power of webpack. This is the glue that allows webpack to do what you're asking of it...

Comment: When I tried it the input files were less than 100b and the output was 971b. And I don't want it to be doing anything client side, just combing the files server side.

Comment: Sounds like you have a bad webpack config, but that wasn't posted here. Make an MVP and post it.

Comment: I did it without a config, I used the code on the homepage for index.js and bar.js and ran it without a config

Comment: That's great, but again I'm not sure what you're expecting. Webpack needs to map your imports/requires internally so they can be closured since they're all going to live in one file. Stitch your files together manually if you don't need the assistance of webpack.

Comment: I was hoping it could just paste in the function at module.exports. Stitching the files together manually is exactly what I'm trying to automate. Right now I use a gulp module but it's not good.